# 6/2*(1+2) is 1 or 9?

Tags: arithmetic, math-software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is 48÷2(9+3)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293)

Please, look at the picture?

[image: http://s16.radikal.ru/i190/1206/3b/7411739c6d9a.jpg]

Which calculator shows true result and how to prove achieved result?

Comment: correct answer is 9

Comment: @avatar why you think so? can you proove your suggestion?

Comment: @BenjaLim: Apparently there was a period some time (more than a year) ago when the site was overwhelmed with variants of this question. Seeing it again must have been a traumatic experience for someone.

Comment: The Casio fx-570MS to the left is a model from 2005, whereas Casio fx-50FH was introduced in 2008, so I would go with the newer calculator on the right. Which, incidentally, has the right answer.

Comment: I have given an answer here which explains why calculators give different results. The question to which it has been originally linked to is somewhat too broad. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2356210/54967

Comment: One of the calculators may be a regular one and the other may be a scientific one. Unlike regular four-function calculators, scientific calculators follow order of operations.

Answer (score 8):

Despite every personal belief, a notation like $a/b(c+d)$ **is** ambiguous. At school I learned that this should be
$$
\frac{a}{b}(c+d),
$$
but even in research papers somebody could read
$$
\frac{a}{b(c+d)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The reason why calculators are giving different results is because one is calculating,

$$\frac{6}{2\cdot(2+1)} = 1$$

while the other is calculating,

$$\frac{6}{2}\cdot(2+1)  = 9$$

Depending on what you want to calculate, you could obtain different answers.

Answer (score 2):

when two operations have same precedence, then the operations are done from left to right.So here, division is done first and then multiplication.This is just a convention.Without this, this expression is ambiguous.