# What the solve for this sentence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$6÷2(1+2)=$?

$6÷2\times3=9$

We need to solve first the parentheses or we can distribute this way:

$6÷(2\times1+2\times2)=$?

$6÷(2+4)=$?

$6÷6=1$

What is the correct? $9$ or $1$?

Comment: Writing an equation like this is very inconvenient. Consider writing it with fractions instead.

Comment: How is this linear algebra? Also - those two expression's aren't even the same, so both are correct...

Comment: is this $$6:2(1+2)$$? if so then the result is $9$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner you mean $6:2(1+2)$

Comment: What you are asking for is $6:2\times 3$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, why is this the correct way? We can't distribute the parentheses content instead?

Comment: See the following: [What is 48÷2(9+3)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48%C3%B7293) or [6/2*(1+2) is 1 or 9?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164152/6-212-is-1-or-9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which is the correct answer depends on whether the intended interpretation was
$$6÷(2(1+2))$$
or
$$(6÷2)(1+2)$$
There would not be the slightest amount of confusion if it were written
$$\frac{6}{2(1+2)}$$
or
$$\frac{6}{2}(1+2)$$

Comment: so, the first equation is wrote from wrong way? we can say that is an invalid equation?

Comment: The first equation is written in a way that is not optimized for clarity. It may even be a deliberate trick question. Even if careful application of operator precedence allows you to unambiguously assign a value, how confident are you that whoever wrote it was as careful as you are?

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=URcUvFIUIhQ) to answer your question. Because answers that just provide links are discouraged — and for good reason too — I will give you some insight on how it approaches the problem. The link takes you to a YouTube video which is entirely dedicated to explaining the correct answer to the equation, $$6\div 2(1 +2) = \, ?$$ It uses an *order-of-operations* technique called **PEDMAS** / **BODMAS** such that, $$\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{PEDMAS} & \mathbf{BODMAS} \\
\hline \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{Parentheses} \quad \ \ \diagup &\mathrm{Brackets} \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{Exponents} \quad \ \ \ \diagup &\mathrm{Orders} \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{Multiplication} \quad — &\mathrm{Division} \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{Addition} \quad \ \ \ \ — &\mathrm{Subtraction} \\
\end{array}$$