# Simple math question

Tags: arithmetic

6/2(2+1) = 9 or 6/2(2+1) = 1
I am not really sure which is the correct answer. I think the latter is much more correct than the former. If we assume the property of distribution then the latter can be made into this 6/2(2+1) = 6/(2*2 + 2*1) = 1.

Comment: $\dfrac{6}{2}(2+1)=9$ while $\dfrac{6}{2(2+1)}=1$.  Which one do you mean?

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164152/6-212-is-1-or-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. The "standard" order of operations is ambiguous when it comes to division and multiplication, and this confusion is best avioded by using parentheses or fractions, writing either
$$
\frac62(2+1)\quad\text{or}\quad\frac6{2(2+1)}
$$
or
$$
(6/2)(2+1)\quad\text{or}\quad6/(2(2+1))
$$

Answer (score 0):

Following the order of operations we get, $$ 6/2(2+1) = (6/2)(3)=3(3)=9 $$

We better avoid confusion by adding another parenthesis.

$$ (6/2)(2+1) =9$$.