# Is there such a thing as an official order of operations?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

I came to this questions because someone posted on Twitter: How much is 8÷2(2+2)

There seems to be some controversy about the order in which the calculations are to be performed. What is the official answer? Is there such a thing as the official answer?

Comment: The first step is alway to *not* use the symbol $÷$ to avoid precisely such ambiguity.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! About your question: It is very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164152/6-212-is-1-or-9), which has been asked many times on MSE.

Comment: If this were written as $\frac{8}{2}\times (2+2)$ or as $\frac{8}{2\times (2+2)}$ there would be no ambiguity.  As you grow and learn about when certain notations are ambiguous, you learn to avoid them, such as using $\sin^{-1}$ to represent the functional inverse of sine.

Comment: As an aside, do be more careful with what tags you use.  "Multiplicative order" has nothing to do with the question you asked and is a group theory concept, something studied during an undergraduate math major.  This is a question on basic arithmetic and order of operations, totally unrelated.

Comment: In my experience at Math Help Forum and Math Help Boards, people who asked this kind of question were very often trolls. Servaes has the right answer. Expressions like these should never be written, and questions like these should not be asked.

Comment: @Servaes Why do you think that the choice of symbol matters?

Comment: @JMoravitz, I tried the tag order-of-operations, but that didn't exist.

Comment: Order-of-operations is a notation thing, so I added the "notation" tag.

Comment: @Servaes, which symbol should I use? Or should I not divide at all?

Comment: Using a fraction bar instead would be a good idea: you can write either $\frac82 (2+2)$ or $\frac{8}{2(2+2)}$.