# Does an inline algebra expression with multiplication in the dividend imply a quantity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Here's a trivial one. Given the inline algebra expression *(2a + b) / 3c* imply that the 3c is a quantity, and that the order of operations should be equivalent to *(2a + b) / (3c)* ? Or should it be understood as *((2a + b) / 3) c* ?

Comment: My instinct: The first. Not making this an "answer" since I don't have a source.

Comment: It's whatever one you like, there is no rule to it. In general avoid such expressions, it doesn't really cost you to use braces or to actually use $\frac{2a+b}{3c}$

Comment: Of intrest [Do values attached to integers have implicit parentheses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/do-values-attached-to-integers-have-implicit-parentheses) and [What is 48÷2(9+3)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48%C3%B7293)

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not aware of any source that specifically says this, I would say that pretty much everyone would (just by "eye") read it the first way, with $3c$ treated as a unit. If you intend the second interpretation and you write it this way, then there is a very high probability you will be misunderstood, so it is not recommended.

[Some sources](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/commerrs/#Fractions) consider expressions like $z/xy$ to be ambiguous. That same link says that "some of the Texas Instruments calculators follow two conventions, according to whether multiplication is indicated by juxtaposition or a symbol", which is actually the convention I would prefer (in case of juxtaposition, the multiplication is treated as a unit).

A computer program will be more strict and quite possibly interpret it in the second way, especially if it does not distinguish between implicit multiplication versus multiplication indicated by a symbol, but if you are writing for human readers the first interpretation should prevail.